# Android Gradle remove resources from apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have set a dependency project using gradle, but this project has a lot of resources which are unused in classes which I am using. Is it possible to somehow filter them?

I have been trying to do it using

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.inputResourceSets.each {
        ResourceSet res ->
            res.sourceFiles.each {
                File s ->
                   //here I identify some source files and then I removed them from sourceFiles
            }

    }
}
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

try [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#)  which is good at finding/remove unused classes.

proguard integration with gradle on release...

build.gradle 'buildTypes'...

```
runProguard true
    proguardFile 'yourProguard.txt'
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing it using proguard (I have never used but I read about it). I was just really hoping for solution using gradle.